# Obtain specific attribute from Magento, and if that attribute value contains specific data, assign specific string to a variable

Tags: php, magento

What I'm attempting to do is obtain the attribute called "*specialproduct*", then look through it for specific types of special product; *garminpilot*, *garminpilotpro*, *garminpilotpremium*, and *garmintrainer*. Then, if those exist on a product, assign a specific text string to the variable *$specialproductmsg*.

This is what I currently have. Is there a better way of doing this at all? Anything more efficient ?

```
$specialtype = $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('specialproduct');

if(in_array($specialtype, array('garminpilot','garminpilotpro','garminpilotpremium','garmintrainer'))) {
    $specialproductmsg = 'You have ordered an online course. Please visit http://example.com/onlinecourse to view your online course.';
}
else {
    $specialproductmsg = '';
}
```

Comment: Nope, not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ternary operator like this :

```
$types = ['garminpilot', 'garminpilotpro', 'garminpilotpremium', 'garmintrainer'];

$specialproductmsg = in_array($specialtype, $types)
    ? 'You have ordered an online course. Please visit http://example.com/onlinecourse to view your online course.' 
    : '';
```